# Confusion about an application of dominated convergence theorem

Tags: limits, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

In "Probability" by Alan F. Karr (p. 172), the following chain of reasoning is used to show that the convergence of characteristic functions implies convergence in distribution.

Let $\{ X_n \}_{n = 1}^\infty$, $X$ be random variables with the characteristic functions converging pointwise $\varphi_{X_n} \longrightarrow \varphi_X$. Because the distribution can be recovered from the characteristic functions at any continuity points $a < b$ by
$$
F_{X_n}(b) - F_{X_n}(a) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita} - e^{-itb}}{it} \varphi_{X_n}(t) \, dt
$$
it follows that
$$
F_X(b) - F_X(a) = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita} - e^{-itb}}{it} \varphi_X(t) \, dt = \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita} - e^{-itb}}{it} \lim_{n \to \infty} \varphi_{X_n} (t) \, dt \\ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{T \to \infty} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-T}^T \frac{e^{-ita} - e^{-itb}}{it} \varphi_{X_n} (t) \, dt = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( F_{X_n} (b) - F_{X_n}(a) \right) 
$$
The dominated convergence theorem is quoted to justify bringing the limit inside the integral outside, but the author goes further and interchanges the limits $T \to \infty$ and $n \to \infty$, and this inference seems to me to be outside the jurisdiction of the DCT. Is this justified by DCT ? If not why is it valid to interchange the limits here ?

Comment: The "proof" is  not an acceptable one. Your questions are legitimate.